# Inserting pandas dataframe into django model

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I am having an issue writing a dataframe to my django models.py.

The file is long, but is quite simple in its methodology:

-import modules

-create django database

-requests.get necessary data

-alter data some to fit my goals, save as df

-connect to django db and insert df

My models.py is the following:

```
from django.db import models
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timezone
from datetime import datetime 
from datetime import date 
from datetime import timedelta
import time
from django.conf import settings
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine


class cryptoData(models.Model):
    coin = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    asset_id = models.SmallIntegerField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    close = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.BigIntegerField()
    market_cap = models.FloatField()
    reddit_posts = models.IntegerField()
    reddit_comments = models.IntegerField()
    tweets = models.IntegerField()
    tweet_favorites = models.IntegerField()
    social_volume = models.IntegerField()


lunarcrush_key = 'fakekey1234'

def top_coins():
    lc_market = requests.get(
        url = 'https://api.lunarcrush.com/v2?data=market&',
        params = {
            'key': lunarcrush_key,      
        }
    )
    all_coins = []
    for entry in lc_market.json().get('data'):
        coin = []
        coin.append(entry.get('s'))
        coin.append(entry.get('mc'))
        all_coins.append(coin)
    all_coins.sort(key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)
    top_ten_coins = all_coins[:10]
    return(top_ten_coins)

top_coins_lst = top_coins()
top_coin_names_lst = [x[0] for x in top_coins_lst]

def get_coin_data(key, coin, date_diff, start_date, end_date):
    lc = requests.get(
        url = 'https://api.lunarcrush.com/v2?data=assets&',
        params = {
            'key': lunarcrush_key,
            'symbol': coin,
            'interval': 'day',
            'data_points': date_diff,
            'start': int(start_date.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()),
            'end': int(end_date.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())       
        }
    )
    metric_names = []
    for entry in lc.json().get('data')[0].get('timeSeries'):
        for key in entry:
            metric_names.append(key) if key not in metric_names else metric_names
    metrics_list = []
    for entry in lc.json().get('data')[0].get('timeSeries'):
        row_list = []
        for key in entry:
            row_list.append(entry.get(key))
        metrics_list.append(row_list)
    metrics_df = pd.DataFrame(metrics_list, columns = metric_names)
    metrics_df['time'] = metrics_df['time'].apply(lambda x : datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    metrics_df['coin'] = coin
    cols = list(metrics_df)
    cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('coin')))
    metrics_df = metrics_df.loc[:, cols]
    return(metrics_df)

def get_all_coins_data(coins_list):
    appended_data = []
    end_date = datetime.now()
    start_date = end_date - timedelta(days = 700)
    date_diff = (end_date - start_date).days
    for coin in coins_list:
        appended_data.append(get_coin_data(lunarcrush_key, coin, date_diff, start_date, end_date))
        time.sleep(.1)
    output = pd.concat(appended_data)
    return(output)

df = get_all_coins_data(top_coin_names_lst)

focused_df = df[['coin', 'asset_id', 'time', 'close', 'volume', 'market_cap', 'reddit_posts', 'reddit_comments', 'tweets', 'tweet_favorites', 'social_volume']]

user = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
password = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
database_name = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']

database_url = 'sqlite://{user}:{password}@localhost:5432/{database_name}'.format(
    user=user,
    password=password,
    database_name=database_name,
)

engine = create_engine(database_url, echo=False)
focused_df.to_sql(cryptoData, con=engine)
```

When I run the `manage.py runserver` command, I get the following error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Invalid SQLite URL: sqlite://user:password@localhost:5432/C:\Users\user\Programming\django_crypto_v6\source\db.sqlite3
Valid SQLite URL forms are:
sqlite:///:memory: (or, sqlite://)
sqlite:///relative/path/to/file.db
sqlite:////absolute/path/to/file.db

I'm struggling to resolve this issue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong pattern for SQLite database_url

see the docs at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlite